# Find a specific coordinate in TikZ Figure

Tags: pgfplots

This is my first time asking something here so let me know if I did something wrong or should change the post in any way.

I am fairly new with TikZ so this might be a very basic question but I haven't found a way to solve it yet. I want to draw a graphic with a coordinate system in it. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I manage to get it with the following set-up:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel={$g_s$},
    ylabel={$g_d$},
    xmin=-0.8, xmax=0.2,
    ymin=-1, ymax=2,
    xtick={-0.8,-0.6,...,0.2},
    ytick={-1,-0.5,...,2},
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=1,
    minor grid style={line width=0.2pt,draw=gray!30,dashed},
    major grid style={line width=0.2pt,draw=gray!30, dashed},
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
  ]
  \end{axis}

\node[circle, draw=black, fill=darkgray, name=G, scale=0.7] at (0,0) {};

  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It works well but then I want to mark some particular points, for instance the origin (0,0). If I put a point on (0,0) it will be placed at the lower left corner of the image and not in the were the origin of my coordinates is
[image]

How can I make so the coordinates match? I tried to shift the TikZ coordinates but I don't know by how much exactly I should do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use the axis coordinates, put the `\draw` inside the `axis` environment (and make sure to use a `\pgfplotsset{compat=...}` greater than 1.11 (1.18 is current).

Comment: Or `(axis cs: 0,0)` but providing a compat version should be the first thing you do after loading the package and with the newest you `axis cs` will be implied.

Comment: Thank you for the sugestions. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which we can compile as it is (so far we not know which version of \pgfplots ypou use).
- As were mentioned in comments, command `\node[circle, draw=black, fill=darkgray, name=G, scale=0.7] at (0,0) {};` should be inside of `axis` environments:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel={$g_s$},
    ylabel={$g_d$},
    xmin=-0.8, xmax=0.2,
    ymin=-1,   ymax=2,
    xtick distance=0.2,
    ytick distance=0.5,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=1,
    grid style={line width=0.2pt,draw=gray!30,dashed},
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
  ]
\node[circle, fill, semitransparent] at (0,0) {}; % change options as you like to have
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it when I get home. Also, I'll keep it in mind qith the MWE